# Sophos Anti-Virus seems not to update

Tags: 18.04, security, antivirus

I have also tried the manual update, but it seems that nothing changes.

It displays:

> Successfully updated Sophos Anti-Virus from sdds:SOPHOS

But the database version does not change.

How to check if I do have the latest version?